# How come Week days in India match with Western system?

Tags: india, prehistory, astronomy

How come Week days in India synchronize with the week days in Western countries? When did this happen?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "synchronize"? Are you perhaps asking the same question as the one here: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/5878/what-is-the-origin-of-indian-weekday-names ?

Comment: Also take a look at: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/11863/is-every-major-culture-in-the-same-year/11864#11864

Comment: This is legitimate question. The seven-day week originated in the Near East and spread with Christianity and Islam. It was introduced into India in the period of Muslim domination. This was long before the British Empire.

Comment: thank you fbd. can you cite supporting references. Dear jwenting, I am at loss- what do you want to convey? Dear litnemo, almost but not exactly.